# What is Shannon's source entropy?

Tags: information-theory, entropy, references

Suppose that ${X_n; Y_n}$ is a random process with a discrete alphabet, that is, taking on values in a discrete set for $n$ data length. They correspond to the input and output of a communication process. Assuming Y to be the discretized output, what is meant by Shannon's source entropy for a given discretization bin $k$ : $H_{source} = lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{k} H_k$ where
 $H_k$ stands for Shannons entropy.

I found this in Stojanovski et al's paper: [Applications of Symbolic Dynamics in Chaos Synchronization](http://bit.ly/OguJkF). Now, [Jun Chen](http://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/~junchen/probIII.pdf) also mentions about source entropy but the formula is very different! Its the same as Shannon's entropy.

So, what exactly is *source entropy*? Is it the entropy of $X$ or $Y$ or is it the same as Shannon's entropy?

Comment: I haven't read the sources you cite, but the definition you quoted appears to be the definition of [entropy rate][1]. For a process where the random variables are i.i.d., the entropy rate equals the entropy of any of the random variables in the process.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate

Comment: In the link which you provided, $n$ implies the number of data samples or the number of quantization levels?Also,source entropy(X) will not be equal to source entropy(Y) or would it be same sinceY is just a discretization of X?

Comment: The idea in the definition of entropy rate is that the random variables $X_n$ form a stochastic process. Therefore, for example, $H(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ is the entropy of the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$, $p(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ (i.e., the so-called joint entropy). Therefore, for example, for i.i.d. random variables, $H(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=H(X_1)H(X_2)...H(X_n)=nH(X_i)$, because of the independence assumption (the joint distribution can be expressed as a product of the individual distributions), where $i$ can be any of $i=1,2,3,...,n$ (that's the result I claimed in my first comment).

Comment: So, when implementing entropy should I take the joint probability  or the probability of the occurence of each symbol?Also, its still unclear for me if I need to calculate entropy of the discretized variable Y or X(raw signal) when the task is to determine the information capacity or the number of bits and hence number of quantization bins the channel can accomodate without error.

Comment: The link to *Applications of Symbolic Dynamics in Chaos Synchronization* did not work for me.